# How to split a list using another list

Tags: python

I have two lists. Both are sorted lists of numbers.  Say:

```
A = [1.1, 5.2, 12.3, 12.6]
B = [2.3, 2.7, 5.2, 11.1, 12.1, 15.6, 16.6]
```

For each number in A I find the nearest value in B.  E.g.

```
1.1 -> 2.3
5.2 -> 5.2
12.3 -> 12.1
12.6 -> 12.1
```

I would now like to split B into a list of lists using this mapping. Each point that some value in A maps to is put as the end of an interval. So I get

```
listoflists = [[2.3], [2.7, 5.2], [11.1, 12.1]]
```

and the remainder is:

```
remainder = [15.6, 16.6]
```

Now I need to transform the values in listoflists into the distance from the value the end of the previous list in listoflists. We assume there is an implicit value at 0. So:

```
transformed_values = [[2.3], [0.4, 2.9], [5.9, 6.9]]
```

remainder is similarly transform to be:

```
transformed_remainder = [3.5, 4.5]
```

I have struggled to write sensible and correct code to output `transformed_values` and `transformed_remainder`.

> How can you compute `transformed_values` and `transformed_remainder` efficiently from the variables `A` and `B`? Perhaps it can be done directly without computing `listoflists` at all?

I do have code to find the nearest value:

```
def find_nearest(array, value):
    idx = np.searchsorted(array, value, transformed_remainderside="left")
    if idx > 0 and (idx == len(array) or math.fabs(value - array[idx-1]) < math.fabs(value - array[idx])):
        return array[idx-1]
    else:
        return array[idx]
```

(I will need to do this a lot so maybe using numpy has too much overhead and using bisect would be better.)

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the purpose of this problem?  It looks interesting enough, but it may help people answering your question what you need it for.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld The lists are sets of times and I need to split one set of times into different intervals using the other one, in short. The full explanation is a little long, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't need help with the `listoflists`.  This is how you can do the transformations.

```
transformed_values = (
    listoflists[0] 
    + [[a - prior[-1], b - prior[-1]] 
       for (a, b), prior in zip(listoflists[1:], listoflists[:-1])]
)
transformed_remainder = [r - listoflists[-1][-1] for r in B[(len(A) + 1):]]
```

Comment: Do you think it can be computed more easily directly from the input A and B without going via listoflists?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```py
a = [1.1, 5.2, 12.3, 12.6]
b = [2.3, 2.7, 5.2, 11.1, 12.1, 15.6, 16.6]

for i in a:
    nearest = None
    nearestNum = None
    for x in b:
        if nearest == None:
            nearest = abs(i - x)
            nearestNum = x
        if abs(i - x) < nearest:
            nearestNum = x
            nearest = abs(i - x)
    if nearestNum:
        print(i, "->", nearestNum)
    else:
        print(i, "-> Not found")

#or

for i in a:
    nearest = []
    nearestNum = None
    for x in b:
        nearest.append(abs(i - x))
    nearest.sort()
    if i + nearest[0] in b:
        nearestNum = i + nearest[0]
    elif i - nearest[0] in b:
        nearestNum = i - nearest[0]
    if nearestNum:
        print(i, "->", nearestNum)
    else:
        print(i, "-> Not found")
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to answer the question.

Comment: My question is about computing transformed_values and transformed_remainder efficiently .